# How can I successfully import a shapefile from ArcGIS to SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, database, arcgis

Summary:
I am having issues with importing the shapefile in ArcGIS Pro into the SQL Server database. It shows an error output and an empty table when it is imported.

The only time I see this is working is when using importing it to a geodatabase, but that way of doing things appears to be deprecated.

More Detailed Information:
I am using ArcGIS Pro version 2.9.8 to import a shapefile to SQL Server database version 15.0.18424.0.

I've tried importing the shapefile as a feature class to the database, and get "error 000210: Cannot create output. Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass)." I get this error from the database type SQL Server.

However, I am able to see the imported shapefile from database type Enterprise Geodatabase in SQL Server. It appears that this way of doing things is deprecated, and I'm having issues getting this to work with database type SQL Server.

I can also see more information on what schema is used with the database type Enterprise Geodatabase in SQL Server, but not with database type SQL Server.

Has anyone had this problem before, or knows what the actual issue might be to be able to fix this problem?

Comment: how does the new table supposed to look? sql server mostly just supports the geometry/geography as a dumb collection of points, while shapefiles are complex objects

Comment: @siggemannen, they new table should show the results of all the fields from the shapefile, and I should also see the spatial results in sql server. What do you mean by it supporting geometry/geography as dumb collection points?